# Splitting jQuery code into reusable modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, refactoring, node-modules

I am in the middle of php app development with some addition of js. Since my JS knowledge is not particularly good, I rely on jQuery. However, I like to work with reusable code rather than spaghetti. So, there is a situation.

I have two kinds of form in the app - classic ones and ajax ones. Now I want to move my ajax form handlers to separated file, module and initate it in main js file. 
Let see my currect code:

**main.js**

```
import forms from './plugins/ajaxForms';

forms.init($('form.ajax'));
```

**ajaxForms.js**

```
function init(form) {
    const obj = this;
    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = $(this);
        const url = form.attr('action');
        const data = form.serialize();
        const method = form.find('input[name="method"]').val() ? form.find('input[name="method"]').val() : form.attr('method');

        const call = $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() {
            obj.beforeSend(form);
            }
        });

        call.done(function (response) {
            Toastr["success"](response.message);
        });

        call.fail(function (response) {
            Toastr["error"](response.responseJSON.message);
            obj.renderErrors(form);
        });

        call.always(function () {
            obj.after(form);
        });
    });
}

function beforeSend(container) {
    if(container === null) {
    return;
    }
    container.find('.form-loading-overlay').show();
}

function after(container) {
    if(container === null) {
    return;
    }
    container.find('.form-loading-overlay').hide();
}

function renderErrors(errors, form) {
    $.each(errors, function (i, e) {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
        let output = '';
        $.each(e, function (i,e) {
            output += e + '<br />';
        });

        form.find('input[name="' + i + '"]')
            .after('<span class="error">' + output + '</span>')
            .addClass('has-error');

    } else {
        form.find('input[name="' + i + '"]')
            .after('<span class="error">' + e + '</span>')
            .addClass('has-error');
    }
    });

}


export default {
    init: init,
    beforeSend: beforeSend,
    after: after,
    renderErrors: renderErrors
};
```

*Note: renderErrors function is not currently working as it has problem with form variable. It doesn't matter right now.*

**Expected solution:**

I do not like the way I am using other functions from this module (such as after(container) - I needed to pass "this" to const obj in order to get it to work with i.e. beforeSend in const call.

In short, I believe there is better way to write this piece of code. I suppose that this particular example is overcomplicated and could be just left as a jquery code closed in submit event. However, I insist on making it modular as I want to learn on this example and refactor rest of my code myself.

Also, I need to be able to access methods like "beforeSend" and "after" without using init() method, as I am referecing to this methods in other modules while using ajax calls without forms - I still want to display loading overlay on given container during ajax action.

Comment: Questions about how to optimize or refactor working code are better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. This site focuses on code that doesn't work

Comment: Oh, didn't know that site. Already posted, thank you for a tip :-)